# Gradle api transitive dependencies not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a library project that I use to hold some setup for my other projects that has a lot of utility classed and also utility libraries included. So, I changed all my "implementation" calls in the library's build.gradle to "api" calls so I don't need to reimport the dependencies again and again. After building the library and moving the jar from my library folder to the lib folder inside my main project, I can access all the classes in my library, but the transitive dependencies are not available in my main project.

I also tried using implementation and transitive = true, but no luck.

I'm using AdoptOpenJDK 16 and Gradle 7.0 and I already tried to rebuild everything after cleaning the cache.

library's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
archivesBaseName = 'utilities'
version = '1.0.2'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Spring
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging')
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    api('io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0')

    // Utilities
    api('io.sentry:sentry-spring:4.3.0')
    api('joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10')
    api('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15')
    api('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0')
    api('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8')
    api('org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1')
    api('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
    api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')

    // Annotation Processor
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
    annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')

    // Tests
    testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
    testAnnotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties = System.properties as Map<String, ?>
}
```

application's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
archivesBaseName = 'application'
version = '1.0.2'

bootJar {
    enabled = true
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir dirs: 'lib'
}

dependencies {

    // Local
    implementation('com.mygroup:utilities:1.0.2')
    testImplementation('com.mygroup:utilities:1.0.2')
    annotationProcessor('com.mygroup:utilities:1.0.2')
    testAnnotationProcessor('com.mygroup:utilities:1.0.2')

    // Additional dependencies
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    implementation('com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2')
    implementation('com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2')
    implementation('com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.2.4')
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties = System.properties as Map<String, ?>
}
```

Comment: can you try a version lower for gradle? it might be because of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information about transitive dependencies isn't included in Your jar. When You publish libraries to a repository via Maven or Gradle, there are several files being published:

- obviously .jar file with all compiled code
- pom.xml file (it contains transitive dependencies definitions)
- some files with checksums

When You just copy Your library jar to `lib` directory, Your application has no information about it's dependencies. There are several solutions:

1. Publish Your library to Maven Repository ([Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss-download) or [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) are most popular products to set up self hosted repository, but You can also use `mavenLocal()`) instead of copying jar to `lib` - I think it's the best solution
2. Build library as fatJar (jar file with compiled code and all it's dependencies - [Creating a Fat Jar in Gradle](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar))
3. Copy all of Your library dependencies to `lib` folder

Comment: Use plugin "maven-publish". It's solve the problem. Here example:  https://tomgregory.com/how-to-use-gradle-api-vs-implementation-dependencies-with-the-java-library-plugin/